# 2 khz noise in neighborhood

Tags: noise

This might be slightly off topic but I'm trying to find the source of a 2.2khz noise in my neighborhood. I live in Astoria, NY near the intersection of two subway/amtrack trains. At seemingly random times, at various decibel levels, averaging about 75db in my house and 85db outside...there is a very annoying noise coming from I don't know where. It's driving me nuts and has been happening off and on again for weeks. Some other neighbors have also noticed the noise. I was wondering if there is a known, common source of noise right around 2.2khz? Like large capacitors or power lines, something like that. Any help would be much appreciated.

I made a recording http://media.jasonormand.com/2khz-noise.ogg

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about sound design.

Comment: While an interesting question, I'm pretty sure this is off topic.  Please comment if you think it should be on topic as I could see sound identification potentially being useful in sound design, but I'm not sure we want to have a broad "name that sound" game on topic.  Glad you found your answer though.

Comment: IDK I enjoy the questions on this forum that are more like "ask a sound designer" than "question about sound design" (as a change of pace, not as the main purpose of this site).  Sound is part of the fabric of everyday life.

Comment: Yeah, it is a little off topic. I was aiming for what I thought was the most appropriate Stack brand. But feel free to remove it if you don't think it's helpful for the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved. It was coming from an HVAC unit at a nearby building that is under construction. It turns out that there was some kind of cover on the unit that was causing the noise. Once the cover was removed (by the kind construction crew) the noise immediately stopped. There was  probably a pinch point acting as some kind of crude whistle. Your hunch was correct @he_artburns, thanks for the tip.

Today is a good day.

Answer (score 1):

The past few weeks is also when heating systems have started coming on in our fair city.  A fan or air channel that is just slightly loose in some way can cause high pitched sounds that are surprisingly loud.  Radiators can whistle and shriek too but it doesn't sound like that to me...more mechanical.  I'd really concentrate and try to follow it to a source, even if you have to wander around like a crazy person a little bit!

I used to live in Astoria, never heard this particular sound anywhere.

Comment: I have indeed already wandered around like a crazy person. I narrowed it to a fairly small radius of about 100ft or so but haven't been able to pin it down completely. The search continues.